# Making card deck in java Class

Tags: java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck{

    final private int CARD_SET = 52;
    final private int NUM_FACE = 13;
    final private int NUM_SUITE = 4;

    private ArrayList<Card> cardSet = new ArrayList<>(52);
    private Card card = new Card();

    public Deck(){

        for(int i = 0; i < CARD_SET; i++){

            if( i >= 0 && i < NUM_FACE) {
                card.setSuite("club");
                card.setFace(i + 1);
            }else if( i >= NUM_FACE && i < NUM_FACE*2 ){
                card.setSuite("diamond");
                card.setFace(i + 1 - NUM_FACE);
            }else if(i >= NUM_FACE*2 && i < NUM_FACE*3){
                card.setSuite("heart");
                card.setFace(i + 1 -(NUM_FACE*2));
            }else if(i >= NUM_FACE*3 && i < NUM_FACE*4){
                card.setSuite("spade");
                card.setFace(i + 1 - (NUM_FACE*3));
            }

            cardSet.add(card);

        }

    }

    public void printDeck(){

        for(Card card : cardSet){

            System.out.println(card.getFace());
            System.out.println(card.getSuite());
        }
    }

}
```

When I call "printDeck()", it shows all the 13 spades in the ArrayList. 
I can't figure out why this codes doesn't work to make a a deck.
Your help will extend my lifespan.

Comment: Because you aren't creating new `Card` instances, you are modifying the same one on each iteration. Move `Card card = new Card()` inside the `for` loop

Comment: You should create a new instance of `Card` for each iteration, not just one for the entire class.

Comment: Relocate Card instance inside the for loop is the only way to solve that out?

Comment: @HyunJung Yes, you need to have a separate instance for each card in the deck. If the instance is the same for all of them, you will have the exact same card in the entire deck.

Comment: @BackSlash What i thought was like once I construct an instance of Card, then during the loop card will be over-initiated so that the ArrayList can have every different card added in.

Comment: @HyunJung No. You have to re-initialize the card each time, otherwise you will just overwrite the contents of the existing card.

Answer (score 0):

You should create new instance of `Card` every time you iterate through the loop.

```
...
public Deck(){

    for(int i = 0; i < CARD_SET; i++){
        Card card = new Card();
        if( i >= 0 && i < NUM_FACE) {
            card.setSuite("club");
            card.setFace(i + 1);
...
```